# How to not run gitlab CI job if directory does not exist

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I would like to write an template that is includeable from our global build template and that will copy a repo's static folder to my static server.

The global build template (build.yml):

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy
include:
  ...
  - local: '/ci-templates/publish_static.yml'
```

which can be used in all repos with (my-app/.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
include:
  - project: 'mycompany/ci-tools'
    file: '/ci-templates/build.yml'
```

Given the repo structure:

```
my-app
│   .gitlab-ci.yml
└───myapp
    └───static
```

The rule would be something like:

```
publish_static:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - export STATIC="$(find . -type d -name static)"
        - rsync -rvv $STATIC deploy@static.server.com:/www/static
```

unfortunately, not all repos have a static folder, and I can't find a way to use `rules:exists` since the static folder isn't in a subfolder that matches `$CI_PROJECT_NAME`.

My attempt to use bash logic:

```
publish_static:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - export STATIC="$(find . -type d -name static)"
        - '[ -d $STATIC ] && rsync -rvv $STATIC deploy@static.server.com:/www/static'
```

causes the job to fail when `[ -d .. ]` fails.

Is there a way to use `rules:exists` that I have overlooked? ..or is there a way to make the last command "succeed" even when the `$STATIC` directory doesn't exist?
(I've added `allow_failure: true`, but we really want the fully green check-icon on our pipelines ;-)

Comment: `not all repos have a static folder, and I can't find a way to use rules:exists since the static folder isn't in a subfolder that matches $CI_PROJECT_NAME.` I do not understand that part. What do you mean "subfolder matches `$CI_PROJECT_NAME`"? Do you want to use globbing?

Comment: What about `[ -d $STATIC ] && rsync... || true`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet that would work :-)

Comment: Did you happen to find a way to do this using `rules:exists`?

Comment: @Ram no, but the `|| true` is working for us.

Answer (score 4):

> not all repos have a static folder, and I can't find a way to use rules:exists since the static folder isn't in a subfolder that matches $CI_PROJECT_NAME.

Do:

```
rules:
  - exists:
       - '*/static'
```

See `Additional details` in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesexists .

Comment: You'll need quotes around `*/static` to pass the syntax check, but it seems that `rules:exists` only checks for files, not directories... (at least my job keeps running)